# Why is webpack creating output js in form of string and using eval function to deploy it?

Tags: javascript, webpack

My webpack.config.js file is as follows:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var ENV = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
var isTest = ENV === 'test' || ENV === 'test-watch';
var isProd = ENV === 'build';

module.exports = function makeWebpackConfig() {
  var config = {};
  if (isTest) {
    config.devtool = 'inline-source-map';
  } else if (isProd) {
    config.devtool = 'source-map';
  } else {
    config.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
  }
  config.debug = !isProd || !isTest;
  config.entry = isTest ? {} : {
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/bootstrap.ts' // our angular app
  };
  config.output = isTest ? {} : {
    path: root('../edu_analytics_prod_front/dist'),
    publicPath: isProd ? '/' : '/',
    filename: isProd ? 'js/[name].[hash].js' : 'js/[name].js',
    chunkFilename: isProd ? '[id].[hash].chunk.js' : '[id].chunk.js'
  };
  config.resolve = {
    cache: !isTest,
    root: root(),
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html'],
    alias: {
      'app': 'src/client',
      'common': 'src/common'
    }
  };
  config.module = {
    preLoaders: isTest ? [] : [{test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'tslint'}],
    loaders: [
      // Support for .ts files.
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts',
        query: {
          'ignoreDiagnostics': [
            2403, // 2403 -> Subsequent variable declarations
            2300, // 2300 -> Duplicate identifier
            2374, // 2374 -> Duplicate number index signature
            2375, // 2375 -> Duplicate string index signature
            2502  // 2502 -> Referenced directly or indirectly
          ]
        },
        exclude: [isTest ? /\.(e2e)\.ts$/ : /\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/, /node_modules\/(?!(ng2-.+))/]
      },
      {test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/, loader: 'file?name=fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]?'},
      {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json'},
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: root('src', 'client'),
        loader: isTest ? 'null' : ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap!postcss')
      },
      // all css required in src/client files will be merged in js files
      {test: /\.css$/, include: root('src', 'client'), loader: 'raw!postcss'},
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: root('src', 'client'),
        loader: isTest ? 'null' : ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap!postcss!sass')
      },
      {test: /\.scss$/, exclude: root('src', 'style'), loader: 'raw!postcss!sass'},
      {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw'}
    ],
    postLoaders: [],
    noParse: [/.+angular2\/bundles\/.+/]
  };
  if (isTest) {
    config.module.postLoaders.push({
      test: /\.(js|ts)$/,
      include: path.resolve('src'),
      loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
      exclude: [/\.spec\.ts$/, /\.e2e\.ts$/, /node_modules/]
    })
  }
  config.plugins = [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        ENV: JSON.stringify(ENV)
      }
    })
  ];
  if (!isTest) {
    config.plugins.push(
      new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: ['vendor', 'polyfills']
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/public/index.html',
        inject: 'body',
        chunksSortMode: packageSort(['polyfills', 'vendor', 'app'])
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: { warnings: false }
      }),
      new ExtractTextPlugin('css/[name].[hash].css', {disable: !isProd})
    );
  }
  if (isProd) {
    config.plugins.push(
      new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: { warnings: false }
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
        from: root('src/public')
      }])
    );
  }
  config.postcss = [
    autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 version']
    })
  ];
  config.sassLoader = {
    //includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss")]
  };
  config.tslint = {
    emitErrors: false,
    failOnHint: false
  };
  config.devServer = {
    contentBase: './src/public',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: 'minimal' // none (or false), errors-only, minimal, normal (or true) and verbose
  };

  return config;
}();

function root(args) {
  args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  return path.join.apply(path, [__dirname].concat(args));
}

function rootNode(args) {
  args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  return root.apply(path, ['node_modules'].concat(args));
}

function packageSort(packages) {
  var len = packages.length - 1;
  var first = packages[0];
  var last = packages[len];
  return function sort(a, b) {
    if (a.names[0] === first) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a.names[0] === last) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.names[0] !== first && b.names[0] === last) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  }
}
```

When I'm running command like ***webpack*** / ***webpack -p***

It is creating three files as follows:

[image: file structure]

But all three files has output as string and using eval function to deploy it and one file has very big size(7 MB) as follows.
[image: code inside]

I want simple JavaScript file without eval used inside it as all other common minification library works and I want to reduce size of vendor file as well.

Comment: Why use webpack if webpack is not doing what you want? Have a dig around the interwebs as it is very easy to just set up your own workflow instead of forcing webpack to do things it was not meant to do.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Your config uses this configuration as default:

```js
config.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
```

The [fine manual](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) states:

> `eval-source-map` - Each module is executed with `eval` and a SourceMap is added as DataUrl to the `eval`.

If you don't want that, use another `devtool` option.

As for decreasing code size, you probably want to either disable the creation of a source map entirely (just don't set the `devtool` option) or have Webpack write the source map to a separate file (`devtool : 'source-map'` or `devtool : 'cheap-source-map'`, AFAIK).

Also set the `NODE_ENV` environment variable to `production` if you want less code:

```bash
# if you're on a Unix-like OS:
env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p
```